# Function to add some values of an array - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sum, addition

If I have an array like the following -

```
$numbers= array(
  'One' => 1,
  'Two' => 2,
  'Three' => 3,
);
```

Is there a function I an use to add together both the values of 'One' and 'Two', and output the value?

If not, how would I go about making that simple function? (This is something i'd be interested in knowing too even if there is a predefined function.)

Comment: You can loop over the array and add the values.

Comment: `echo $numbers['One'] + $numbers['Two']`

Comment: @DiegoMariani no no no this can't be it, it's waaaaaaaaaaaaaay too simple

Comment: @D_isforPaul, show how do imagine the expected output

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I expect the output just to be "3" (2+1)...

Comment: @DiegoMariani that's good for a small array, but if you had an array with 1000 values, and you wanted the sum of the first 400, your method doesn't seem efficient. Would there be a function to get the sum of the first 400?

Comment: @D_isforPaul That's a completely different question. Then you probably want to look at `array_sum()` and `array_slice()`

Comment: @Rizier123 - Sorry if it is. By my original question I meant the sum of the first two values. I'll look into array_sum() and array_slice() - Thanks.

Comment: @@D_isforPaul the question has no a proper context specified as you said. I provided the answer for the base case

Comment: @DiegoMariani I know, that's why i clarified for you in my reply. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use two array function.

> **array_slice()** returns the sequence of elements from the array array as
>   specified by the offset and length parameters.

**Basic Format of array_slice().**

`array_slice(array, start, length, preserve)`

So,

**start:** Numeric value. Specifies where the function will start the slice. 0 = the first element. If this value is set to a negative number, the function will start slicing that far from the last element. -2 means start at the second last element of the array.

**length:**
Numeric value. Specifies the length of the returned array. If this value is set to a negative number, the function will stop slicing that far from the last element. If this value is not set, the function will return all elements, starting from the position set by the start-parameter.

> **array_sum()** returns the sum of values in an array.

**Your array:**

```
$numbers= array(
  'One' => 1,
  'Two' => 2,
  'Three' => 3,
);
```

**Function**

```
echo $arr_sum = array_sum(array_slice($numbers, 0, 2));
```

**Output:**

```
3
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for - Thank you.

I have a follow up issue though. My output seems to be multiplying the answer by 2 - From what i gather. I have a array $monthsdays - with the key as the months, and the value as the days.

My function is "echo $arr_sum = array_sum(array_slice($monthsDays, 4, 6));" - 

In my array index 4 is May => 31, index 5 is June => 30, index 6 is July => 31.

This function is giving me back 184. I can't figure out why it is doing that at all!

Sorry if i havnt replied properly. I'm new to this, and i can't find a better way to reply to you with code :/

Comment: 4 is the starting and 6 is the number of index, sorry for my lacking in the answer. I will update it by providing the additional info. check and accept.

Comment: Ahhhh..of course. Silly mistake. My brain for some reason picked up 'length' as which index to stop at! Thank you very much for your help :)